# jQuery validation plugin not validating the fields onblur and onkeyup

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validation plugin to validate the form data. It works fine on form submit. But `onkeyup` and `onblur` it is not working.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

### jQuery code:

```
var validator = $("#myForm").validate( {

        rules:{
            attribute: "required",
            attributeValue: "required email"
        },
        messages:{
            attribute: "Required",
            attributeValue: {
                required: "Enter email",
                email: "Enter valid email"
            }
        }
    });
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Assuming your `.validate()` is wrapped inside a DOM ready event hander, there is nothing wrong with your code, and the plugin will validate `onfocusout` and `onkeyup` by default.  Perhaps you should consider using a newer version of jQuery than 1.5.2, since you're using v1.11 of the plugin.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/rfKaE/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#element").blur(function(){
   $(this).validate({
      // your code here
   })
})
```

or more precisely

```
$('#myForm').blur(function(){
    validator.validate()
});
```

Comment: Try this in your function.. onfocusout: function(e) {
            this.element(e);
        }

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. I tried and still it is not working when i integrate the logic with my code..

Answer (score 1):

```
Please include key up event or blur event in your validate function

var validator = $("#myForm").validate( {
    //this setting for on key up event
    onkeyup: function(element) { $(element).valid(); },
    rules:{
        attribute: "required",
        attributeValue: "required email"
    },
    messages:{
        attribute: "Required",
        attributeValue: {
            required: "Enter email",
            email: "Enter valid email"
        }
    }
});

if($("#myForm").valid()) {
    // call the function which you want to call after validation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below snippet for onblur in the Validate function:

```
onfocusout: function (element) {
            $(element).valid();
        }
```

so it will become as follows:

```
var validator = $("#myForm").validate( {

    rules:{
        attribute: "required",
        attributeValue: "required email"
    },
    onfocusout: function (element) {
        $(element).valid();
    },
     messages:{
        attribute: "Required",
        attributeValue: {
            required: "Enter email",
            email: "Enter valid email"
        }
    }
});
```

So now you will be able to validate the inputs on blur.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried adding a class name on your input tags?

```
<input type="text" class="require email" name="email"/>
```